# Python MYSQL querys too slow, what is the reason. Optimizing possible with good indexes?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, docker, query-optimization

im running now a mysql docker container image on a hosted server with 2cores 14gb ram 8000 iops max
i do frequently select and update querys

i do use python with mysql-connector

im init a connection at start
i had better performance opening a connection at beginning and 
close it only on exit

```
def initsql():
    logger.log('initsql()')
    global cnx
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='blabla', password='blabla',
                                  host='blablahost',
                                  database='blablabladb')
def closesql():
    logger.log('closesql()')
    global cnx
    cnx.close()
```

Now 2 Functions that are really slow:

```
def sqlSetModus(modus):
    logger.log('sqlSetModus()')
    t0 = time.time()
    try:
        internet_on()  #Function check if there is a internet connection if not raise Exception()
        global cnx
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        global logintoken
        currentdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        if modus == 'offline':
            updateModus = '''UPDATE accounts SET inuse=0, token='none', was_online = '%s', modus = '%s' WHERE token = '%s' ''' % (currentdate, modus, logintoken)
        else:
            updateModus = '''UPDATE accounts SET was_online = '%s', modus = '%s' WHERE token = '%s' ''' % (currentdate, modus, logintoken)
        cursor.execute(updateModus)
        cnx.commit()
        logger.success("sqlSetModus after {} Sekunden".format(time.time() - t0))
        return True
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Error sqlSetModus after {} Sekunden".format(time.time() - t0))
        raise Exception
    finally:
        cursor.close()

def sqlUpdatePoints(company):
    logger.log('sqlUpdatePoints()')
    t0 = time.time()
    try:
        internet_on()
        global cnx
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        global sessiontoken
        currentdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        pointsvalue = 0.55
        updateOnline = '''UPDATE accounts SET was_online = '%s', this_points = this_points + '%s' WHERE token = '%s' ''' % (currentdate, pointsvalue, logintoken)
        cursor.execute(updateOnline)

        updatePoints = '''UPDATE points SET points = points + '%s' WHERE company = 'companyXYZ' ''' % (pointvalue,)
        cursor.execute(updatePoints)

        updateAccount = '''INSERT INTO statistic (company, datum, website) VALUES ('companyXYZ', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1''' % (currentdate, company)
        cursor.execute(updateAccount)

        cnx.commit()
        logger.success("sqlSetAfterSuccesplay after {} Sekunden".format(time.time() - t0))
        return True
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Error sqlSetAfterSuccesplay after {} Sekunden".format(time.time() - t0))
        raise Exception
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

i have of course more code and also more sql querys like simple selects, but these do work fast

these 2 functions cost always more than 10 seconds

sqlUpdatePoints times:

```
[17:38:57.790] sqlUpdatePoints after 13.4862029552 Sekunden
[17:39:48.294] sqlUpdatePoints after 14.960242033 Sekunden
```

sqlSetModus times:

```
[17:38:44.051] sqlSetModus after 14.4736759663 Sekunden
[17:39:31.702] sqlSetModus after 13.1622648239 Sekunden
[17:40:09.977] sqlSetModus after 16.7646770477 Sekunden
```

simple select querys time:

```
[17:39:53.213] sqlGetActiveAccount after 0.741001844406 Sekunden 
[17:39:02.695] sqlGetActiveAccount after 0.737174034119 Sekunden
[17:38:12.800] sqlGetActiveAccount after 0.7693400383 Sekunden
```

you have to know that im running like 100 instances of this code on the same time, means that these are the times when 100 connections are opened
and frequently sqlUpdatePoints + sqlSetModus and simple querys are runned against the database

- how can i faster the queries up.
- is there a speed boost if i do declare good primary keys / indexes? if yes what should be a primary key or a index.
  how can i figure out to set them?

table looks like that:

```
nr = int (autoincrement unique)
username = varchar
password = varchar
inuse = int
token = varchar
was_online = datetime
points = float
modus = enum

nr | username | password | inuse | token | was_online | this_points | modus
```

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL; that will help us focus on indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which indexes you already have, so I'll assume you don't have any:

- For the `sqlSetModus()` function you need the index:

  ```
  create index ix_account_token on accounts (token);
  ```
- For the `sqlUpdatePoints()` function you need the index:

  ```
  create index ix_points_company on points (company);
  ```

You are using equality for the filters (`=`) so with these indexes your searches (updates) should be blazing fast.

Comment: thank you i appreciate your answer, are these two indexes enough, so there is no need for primary key, or any more index that is possible for speed up?

Comment: If you specified primary keys, then those indexes are in place already. There are no more indexes that can speed up these queries (they are quite simple tbh).

Comment: i couldn't find any easy understandable to direct use on my scenario explanation. now i did even understand the reason for these 2 indexes, so using equality filter "=" i just have to index what im searching for right??  i did defined some primary keys and indexes before , and didnt even knowed if they are useful, i just indexed not what was in the "where" part, i indexed all what was after Update rows.  now  I've done it know like you said, and no query does takes longer than 2 seconds, even having 100 parallel connections and frequently updating selecting from database :-) thank you

Comment: If you can spare some time I would recommend the book "SQL Performance Explained - Markus Winand". There's a difference between the operators the SQL optimizer uses. It was probably using a Full Table Scan, and now is using an Index [Range] Seek. Your case was the perfect scenario for an improvement. Nevertheless, not all the cases are as good as yours, and sometimes there isn't much that can be done to improve performance.